# Adding class li element to jQuery tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the tab-content.js url - http://collabedit.com/ja524

I need to add `selected` class to all `li` elements in `ch_tabs` div.

jQuery

```
$('.ch_tabs').click(function () {
 $('.ch_tabs').each(function (index) {
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<li class=""><a class="ch_tabs" href="#ch1"><img alt="arb" src="../images/danish.png"> <span>A</span></a>
                            </li>
<li class=""><a class="ch_tabs" href="#ch1"><img alt="arb" src="../images/danish.png"> <span>B</span></a>
                            </li>
```

Only `selected` class is not getting added, all other classes work.

I doubt this is due to tab-plugin. Is there a way to execute the code after the tab-plugin has executed its operation ?

Comment: Try adding `$(this).closest('li').addClass('selected');`?

Comment: `.each` is redundant, you don't need it

Comment: @PraveenKumar, it is as good as `$('.ch_tabs').parent('li').addClass('selected')` which is surely not intention of OP

Comment: i guess something is tab-content plugin is stopping it to work

Comment: @KunwarbirS. Did you click on teh tab?

Comment: any other class except `selected` works

Comment: Yes i click on the tab and need to add `selected` class to all tabs.

Comment: plugin - http://collabedit.com/ja524

Comment: Please check whether your plugin or code have `selected` class. May be you are getting this problem because no style to that class.

Comment: i have style for `selected` class.

Comment: `selected` class is given only to the tab clicked, but i need to add explicitly `selected` class to other tabs to.

Comment: Is there a way to run my code after the tab-plugin has executed its code ... ?

Comment: Please create a JSFIDDLE, It may solve your problem.

Comment: Share sufficient code to understand your answer. You mention `ch_tabs` `div` but it is not in your HTML. What's the structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this example

CSS:

```
.selected{color:#FF0000;}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li><a class="selected" href="#">A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#list li a').on('click', function(){
    $('li a.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sf1q8rxz/